# Why doesn't RSolve work here?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, difference-equations

```
RSolve[
  {θ[n + 1] == θ[n] + 0.25*ϕ[n], 
   ϕ[n + 1] == ϕ[n] - 2.5*Sin[θ[n]], 
   θ[0] == π/2, ϕ[0] == 0}, 
  {θ[n], ϕ[n]}, n]
```

What's wrong with my code? I know already that a `Sin` is a problem here, but don't know why. Can someone can help?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  Mathematica simply cannot solve this equation.

Comment: If you solve it numerically (with exact numbers), actually it won't be surprising that Mathematica cannot find a general solution in terms of `n`. E.g. `phi[5]` is `-5 - 5/2 Cos[5/8] - 5/2 Cos[15/8] - 5/2 Cos[15/8 + 1/4 (5 + 5/2 Cos[5/8])]`. I wouldn't expect a simple closed form expression in terms of `n` to be able to produce such results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.